# Create a neverending loop within .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to give each list element a different colour. However, I only have 2 colours **but 10 permalinks**.

My problem:

I want the colors to loop again, as long as there are permalinks.

```
  var colors = ['#ff9f9d', '#EB1B53'];

  $('a.permalink').each(function(i) {
      $(this).css('color', colors[i]);
      console.log($(this));
  });
```

What's the best way to make sure it starts the colours array again, if it reaches the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the modulus operator to get the reminder like

```
var colors = ['#ff9f9d', '#EB1B53'];

$('a.permalink').each(function (i) {
    $(this).css('color', colors[i % colors.length]);
    console.log($(this));
});
```

it can be shorten as

```
$('a.permalink').css('color', function (i) {
    return colors[i % colors.length];
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GUEpy/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use simple `modulo` math here,

```
$('a.permalink').each(function(i) {
      $(this).css('color', colors[i%2]);
      console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: if i have more then 2 value in array what can i do? so it will be going to negative vote - bala

Comment: Negative vote does not matter here.. I have a satisfaction that I just figured out a solution in less than half a second for this question. That is enough for me...! :)

Comment: you to write more dynamically like as @arun - bala

Comment: i am not satisfied with your answer. so i put negative vote for you dear - bala

Comment: Thanks. +1. I will be using the `.length` but this was helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not the most performant one i guess but you get the idea:

```
var colors = ['#ff9f9d', '#EB1B53'];


$('a.permalink').each(function() {
    $(this).css('color', colors.reverse()[1]);
    console.log($(this));
});
```